# Pass in a list of possible routes to Flask?

Tags: python, api, flask, routes

I'm learning Flask and have a question about dynamic routing: is it possible to pass in a list of accepted routes? I noticed the `any` converter which has potential but had a hard time finding examples of it in use. Basically I have different groups of endpoints that should trigger the same action amongst them. Here's what I mean:

```
cities = [New York, London, Tokyo]
food = [eggs, bacon, cheese]
actions = [run, walk, jump]
```

I could do something like

```
@app.route('/<string:var>', methods = ['GET'])
def doSomething(var):
    if var in cities:
         travel(var)
    else if var in food:
         eat(var)
    else if var in action:
         perform(var)
```

But is there any way I can do something like this?

```
@app.route('/<any(cities):var>', methods = ['GET'])
    def travel(var):

@app.route('/<any(food):var>', methods = ['GET'])
    def eat(var)

@app.route('/<any(actions):var>', methods = ['GET'])
    def perform(var)
```

**Additionally**, I want these lists to be dynamic. So what I really want is something like:

```
cities = myDb.("SELECT cities FROM country")
@app.route('/<any(cities):var>', methods = ['GET'])
    def travel(var):
```

Is there any way to achieve this, or am I stuck blocking everything up in one dynamic route?

Comment: As I understood, `var` in body of `travel`(for route `@app.route('/<cities:var>')`) should be instance of `City` from db?

Answer (score 10):

Flask is based on [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) and it has the [AnyConverter](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0.12.2/werkzeug/routing.py#L971) to do that.

Basically it allows you to declare a [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) rule like this:

```
Rule('/<any(about, help, imprint, class, "foo,bar"):page_name>')
```

So basically for flask it translates into:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/<any('option1', 'option2'):segment>")
def hello(segment):
    return "Hello {}!".format(segment)

app.run()
```

Or if you want those list to be dynamically generated when the app starts:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

options = ['option1', 'option2']


@app.route("/<any({}):segment>".format(str(options)[1:-1]))
def hello(segment):
    return "Hello {}!".format(segment)


app.run()
```

Comment: P.S. This rule works too: `"/<any(option1, option2):segment>"`.

Answer (score 0):

This takes any string, checks the lists and calls the corresponding function:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

food = ['eggs', 'bacon', 'cheese']
actions = ['run', 'walk', 'jump']
cities = ['New York', 'London, Tokyo']  # or
# cities = myDb.("SELECT cities FROM world")

@app.route('/<string:var>')
def doSomething(var):
    if var in cities:
        return travel(var)
    elif var in food:
        return eat(var)
    elif var in actions:
        return perform(var)
    else:
        # prevent error
        return 'not found'

def travel(var):
    return 'travel to ' + var

def eat(var):
    return 'eat some ' + var

def perform(var):
    return 'have fun and ' + var

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```